# imagettftext not showing numbers only letters

Tags: php, imagettftext

this is my code:

```
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');  

$image_width = 400; 
$image_height = 30; 
$im = imagecreatetruecolor($image_width, $image_height);


$white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255); 
$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0); 
imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 399, 29, $white);


$text = utf8_encode("test 123 abc");

$font = 'myfont.ttf';

imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 10, 20, $black, $font, $text);  
imagejpeg($im); 
imagedestroy($im);
```

can anyone help me find where i am wrong.

Comment: Does your font contains numbers? Try with another font.

Comment: _A note:_ There's no extra points for writing code in as few lines as possible. Try to keep one expression per line and your code will be _way_ more readable.

Comment: Did you find the issue?